# trying to restore vertical scrollbar in code editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  the vertical strip with micro view of code preview on the righthand side of the code editor pane was annoying so I selected some type of option to remove it.  But then I realized that vertical strip provides a vertical scrollbar for the code in the code editor pane and now I need to use alternative approaches to scroll vertically.  I'm not able to find a way to re-enable that scrollbar.  I even selected the menu item for Window > Reset Window Layout but that didn't restore the vertical scrollbar.  Any idea how I can go about restoring that vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure **Show vertical scroll bar** is enabled in Visual Studio options:

[image]